# how to click a text with underline for showing a web?

Tags: cocoa

I want to click a text on the panel with a underline and the text color is blue, and then show a web , I know how to show a web , but how to define the text , in nib when I put a label on the window , I found the label didn't respond for the action , when I put a button with no border I found that I didn't edit the text attribute of the button ,  which module should I put on that and how to edit that text attribute?Thanks a lot. 
The impact I want to show is :   http://stackoverflow.com

Comment: Could you post some code, to clarify what you're trying to do? Perhaps screenshots to demonstrate the difference between expected and actual behaviour?

Comment: He wants to make a hyperlink.

Comment: yes , I want to make a hyperlink ,but it is a button with the text ,so I can respond for the click action .

Answer (score 2):

You could use an NSTextField with attributed text marked with NSLinkAttributeName.

Check out this Apple example http://developer.apple.com/qa/qa2006/qa1487.html

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you add a WebView and then you can put html directly in there?